# Same class invoke NOT effective in Spring AOP cglib

Tags: java, aop, cglib

Suppose we have following class

```
@Service
class MyClass {

    public void testA() { 
        testB();
     }

    @Transactional
    public void testB() { ... }
}
```

Now, if we invoke `myClass.testA();` in test, then `@Transactional` on `testB` will not take effect. The reason I think is following.

Cglib will create a proxy bean for `MyClass`, like this:

```
Class Cglib$MyClass extends MyClass {

    @Override
    public void testB() {
        // ...do transactional things
        super.testB();
    }
}
```

Now we invoke `myClass.testA()`, which will invoke `MyClass.testB()` instead of `Cglib$MyClass.testB()`. So `@Transactional` is not effective. (Am I right?)

I tried to add `@Transactional` for both methods (i.e. `testA()` and `testB()`). The proxy class should like this.

```
Class Cglib$MyClass extends MyClass {

    @Override
    public void testA() {
        // ...do transactional things
        super.testA();
    }

    @Override
    public void testB() {
        // ...do transactional things
        super.testB();
    }
}
```

In this case, although we successfully invoke `Cglib$MyClass.testA()`, it will still goes to `MyClass.testB()`.

So my conclusion is, two methods in same class invoking each other will make aop annotation fail to take effect, unless we use `AopContext.currentProxy()`.

Am I right on above guess? Thanks very much for advice!

Answer (score 5):

It is a well-known and [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) (please search for the term "self-invocation") fact that Spring AOP, due to its proxy-based nature, does not and cannot capture internal method calls like `this.someMethod(..)`.

So as you said, you either need to explicitly refer to the exposed proxy object or alternatively switch from Spring AOP to full [AspectJ via load-time weaving](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it right. The proxy looks something more like this:

```
class Cglib$MyClass extends MyClass {

  MyClass delegate;

  @Override
  public void testB() {
    // ...do transactional things
    delegate.testB();
  }
}
```

Any call is forwarded by Spring which is why your nested annotations are not activated.

Also, if a virtual method like `testA` was overridden, Spring could not avoid to invoke the overridden method.