# Behaviour of lite @Bean methods in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring

From the [Spring 5 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core)

> When @Bean methods are declared within classes that are not annotated
> with @Configuration they are referred to as being processed in a
> 'lite' mode. Bean methods declared in a @Component or even in a plain
> old class will be considered 'lite', with a different primary purpose
> of the containing class and an @Bean method just being a sort of bonus
> there. For example, service components may expose management views to
> the container through an additional @Bean method on each applicable
> component class. In such scenarios, @Bean methods are a simple
> general-purpose factory method mechanism.
>
> **Unlike full @Configuration, lite @Bean methods cannot declare
> inter-bean dependencies**. Instead, they operate on their containing
> component’s internal state and optionally on arguments that they may
> declare. **Such an @Bean method should therefore not invoke other @Bean
> methods; each such method is literally just a factory method for a
> particular bean reference, without any special runtime semantics.** The
> positive side-effect here is that no CGLIB subclassing has to be
> applied at runtime, so there are no limitations in terms of class
> design (i.e. the containing class may nevertheless be final etc).
>
> The @Bean methods in a regular Spring component are processed
> differently than their counterparts inside a Spring @Configuration
> class. **The difference is that @Component classes are not enhanced with
> CGLIB to intercept the invocation of methods and fields**. CGLIB
> proxying is the means by which invoking methods or fields within @Bean
> methods in @Configuration classes creates bean metadata references to
> collaborating objects; **such methods are not invoked with normal Java
> semantics but rather go through the container in order to provide the
> usual lifecycle management and proxying of Spring beans even when
> referring to other beans via programmatic calls to @Bean methods.** In
> contrast, invoking a method or field in an @Bean method within a plain
> @Component class has standard Java semantics, with no special CGLIB
> processing or other constraints applying.

I would have expected that the following code throws an exception / bean1.bean2 to be null and that the init method would not be executed. However, the code below runs fine and prints:

```
Should never be invoked
Expected null but is ch.litebeans.Bean2@402bba4f
```

So for me it looks like lite beans behave the same as beans constructed from an @Configuration annotated class. Can someone point out in which scenario this is not the case?

.

```
package ch.litebeans;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
        Bean1 bean1 = ctx.getBean(Bean1.class);
        System.out.println("Expected null but is " + bean1.getBean2());
    }
}

package ch.litebeans;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ch.litebeans"})
public class ApplicationConfig {}

package ch.litebeans;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Factory1 {
    @Bean
    public Bean1 getBean1(Bean2 bean2){
        return new Bean1(bean2);
    }
}

package ch.litebeans;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Factory2 {
    @Bean(initMethod = "init")
    public Bean2 getBean2(){
        return new Bean2();
    }
}

package ch.litebeans;

public class Bean1 {
    private Bean2 bean2;
    public Bean1(Bean2 bean2){
        this.bean2 = bean2;
    }
    public Bean2 getBean2(){
        return bean2;
    }
}

package ch.litebeans;

public class Bean2 {
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Should never be invoked");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the explanation of Mike Hill I added an example demonstrating the difference:

```
public class BeanLiteRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext acac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyComponent.class,
                MyConfiguration.class);
        MyComponent.MyComponentBean1 componentBean1 = acac.getBean(MyComponent.MyComponentBean1.class);
        MyComponent.MyComponentBean1 componentBean2 = acac.getBean(MyComponent.MyComponentBean1.class);

        MyConfiguration.MyConfigurationBean1 configurationBean1 = acac.getBean(MyConfiguration
                .MyConfigurationBean1.class);
        MyConfiguration.MyConfigurationBean1 configurationBean2 = acac.getBean(MyConfiguration
                .MyConfigurationBean1.class);
    }
}

@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Bean
    public MyComponent.MyComponentBean1 getMyComponentBean1(){
        return new MyComponent.MyComponentBean1(getMyComponentBean2());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyComponent.MyComponentBean2 getMyComponentBean2(){
        return new MyComponent.MyComponentBean2();
    }


    public static class MyComponentBean1{
        public MyComponentBean1(MyComponent.MyComponentBean2 myComponentBean2){

        }
    }

    public static class MyComponentBean2{
        public MyComponentBean2(){
            System.out.println("Creating MyComponentBean2");
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyConfigurationBean1 getMyConfigurationBean1(){
       return new MyConfigurationBean1(getMyConfigrationBean2());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyConfigurationBean2 getMyConfigrationBean2(){
        return new MyConfigurationBean2();
    }


    public static class MyConfigurationBean1{
        public MyConfigurationBean1(MyConfigurationBean2 myConfigurationBean2){}
    }

    public static class MyConfigurationBean2{
        public MyConfigurationBean2(){
            System.out.println("Creating MyConfigrationBean2");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as expected

```
> Creating MyComponentBean2 
> Creating MyComponentBean2 
> Creating MyConfigrationBean2
```

Comment: Try to rename the getter `getBean2()` to something else in class `Bean1`.

Comment: @NiVeR Thanks, I just tried it and it makes no difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330618/bean-inside-class-with-configuration-and-witout-it?rq=1

Comment: @Pavel: That question does not apply here, because the OP is asking about a new feature in Spring 5.

Comment: Was it working correctly in Spring 3.0? The feature is since version 3.0, maybe it's a bug in 5.0?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not a bug. Spring's lite bean definitions are automatically added to the context during the component scan. Bean definitions using a factory method (i.e., all `@Bean`-defined beans) will automatically attempt to autowire parameters using the current context. See [`ConstructorResolver#instantiateUsingFactoryMethod`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/92eaf9906776144ef066a17f982089a593ec9f29/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java#L360) for more details.

The referenced documentation is perhaps not entirely clear. The primary differentiation between "lite" and "full" bean configurations is strictly the proxying that is done in "full" (`@Configuration`) mode. Take for example what would happen if we instead defined our beans in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Bean1 bean1() {
        return new Bean1(bean2());
    }

    @Bean
    public Bean2 bean2() {
        return new Bean2();
    }
}
```

The call to `bean2()` from within `bean1()` will actually reference the *singleton* `bean2` instance from the context rather than directly calling the `bean2()` method as implemented. In fact, it doesn't matter how many `bean2()` method calls are made from within that configuration class -- the real `bean2` method will only be executed one time.

"Lite"-mode does not proxy these methods, meaning that each `bean2()` method call will actually directly reference the method implementation and will **not** return the bean that is in the context. Rather, it will create a new separate instance that is not tracked by the context (as is the default Java behavior).

Comment: Thanks, Mike. The question I have now is how then `@Configuration` works internally? `@Configuration` uses CGLIB for proxying, but CGLIB doesn't support "self-invocation" (because it uses runtime weaving). How is it possible that self-invocated calls are in fact intercepted? The only reasonable explanation at that time if spring itself uses AspectJ internally for compile-time weaving, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that cglib constraint. Are you sure it applies to cglib? I only see it in docs for Spring AOP proxies. Not too familiar with the impls for AspectJ/ASM/cglib/etc. It looks like Spring is using cglib to generate a subclass of the targeted type with overridden methods, which doesn't seem to have self-invocation issues: [ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b2704e1db64098410e1a515fe2c8f757da44b780/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java#L306)

Comment: I would say I'm 90% sure. Look at this: `https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies` and `this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921388/same-class-invoke-not-effective-in-spring-aop-cglib`. The reason I'm asking is to fully understand this concept.Please correct me if I'm wrong and any point.

Comment: @skryvets it doesn't look like this is an limitation of cglib, but rather how Spring chooses to use cglib. The key seems to be in the `ConfigurationClassEnhancer` implementation, but somebody with more Spring/cglib knowledge would have to chime in if you're looking for more info.