# When to use lite mode @Bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Spring doc [mentions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) "lite" mode `@Bean` where the annotation is declared not within a `@Configuration` class.

The primary [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620973/2160440) seems to be whether the `@Bean` method is proxied by cglib.

But practically, when is it a good fit to use lite mode `@Bean` methods (over a plain java method)?

Comment: The short answer never, as it only leads to unexpected behavior. A lite bean method is basically just a simple factory method, each time it is called it will create a new instance (that is the lite part, and the part that leads to confusion).

Comment: It can be used when there is requirement to have two beans (instances) of same type, where each instance behaves differently (different constructor args etc.).

Comment: We can define a bean using @Bean annotation on a method. But I can't think of any real use case that you will need to call that particular bean method directly.