# How to use different spring transactions for different methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I am having a problem with the persistence of a method that is calling another methods to do persistence at my oracle db.

I will try to explain as better as i can to make more easy to you guys, I hope that you can help me.

This is my scenario.

I have a component, in which i am calling a method that looks like that:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    service1.method1(); // @Transactional
    service2.method2(); // @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    service3.method3(); // @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
}
```

The thing is that i need to persist every method separately in case that one of them gets an exception, the others could be persisted.

Right now the problem i have is that i am having a deadlock and my code stills running until i stop my application, and the transactions never end.

I tried so many things, but i am trying without the needed knowledge to work with this spring transactions and i do not know what more i can try to do.

Can you bring me some light on this dark hole where i am right now?

Really, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Spring AOP same class method will not works . this.method1(); // @Transactional will not work.

more explanation in this thread [Same class invoke NOT effective in Spring AOP cglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921388/same-class-invoke-not-effective-in-spring-aop-cglib)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i have to say that inside this method1 method2 and method3, i am calling another methods in another services, and is there where i am defining the @Transaction anotation, i am going to edit that in that post, thanks!

Comment: looks like connection is not getting . please check below property if spring boot spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 20000 
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 100
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000 
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =false

Comment: Actually, i am not using hikari, i am working with jpa, saving entities with a saveAndFlush. And the problem is happening at the end of the method3, when trying to do a saveAndFlush of entities. Thanks

Comment: I think its connection pool issue . just check the logs any pool are using . its better to use one  if not exist https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling

Comment: I see, i didn't know that spring boot by defaults use hikari, i am going to read about this, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

u can register different transactionManager, and ur services use its @Transactional(tx="xxx")